# how to get the string between two same characters of a string - in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

i am having a string like
~AS DF~GHJ~K LE~RTYUVD~FE~GRF E~SRRRTR EDC~XCE

i want the string between "~"
like

AS DF

GHJ

K LE

RTYUVD

FE

GRF E

SRRRTR EDC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Split()` function to split input string by tilde (`~`). Then, since you only interested in substrings **between** tilde, skip the first and last item in the split result :

```
Dim splitResult = "~AS DF~GHJ~K LE~RTYUVD~FE~GRF E~SRRRTR EDC~XCE".Split("~")
For Each r As String In splitResult.Skip(1).Take(splitResult.Length - 2)
    Console.WriteLine(r)
Next
```

Result :

[image]

We skip the first item because it only has tilde at the right side

```
first item~.....
```

and we skip the last item because it only has tilde at the left side

```
.....~last item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Method 1:**

```
Dim s As String = "~AS DF~GHJ~K LE~RTYUVD~FE~GRF E~SRRRTR EDC~XCE"

' Split the string on the backslash character
Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {"~"c})

' Loop through result strings with For Each
Dim part As String
For Each part In parts
    Console.WriteLine(part)
Next
```

**Method 2:**

```
Dim s As String = "~AS DF~GHJ~K LE~RTYUVD~FE~GRF E~SRRRTR EDC~XCE"
Dim words As String() = s.Split(new String() { "~" }, 
                                        StringSplitOptions.None)
```